# How to print multiple small PDF files on one sheet of A4 paper, the easy way?

Tags: pdf, printing, printer, label, label-printer

I need to print a set of small (60x60mm) PDF labels on an sticky A4 paper, which will supposedly be 4x3 grid, with 12 labels in total on one sheet. Thanks in advance

Comment: That's probably he paid version (currently known as *Adobe Acrobat DC*, as opposed to the free *Adobe Acrobat **Reader** DC*). This has a *'multiple page'* feature in the print dialog box.

Comment: Even the free reader has a Multiple feature, but it allows you to print multiple pages *from the currently open PDF* to a single sheet. I don't think it, or the similar feature in Acrobat, allows printing from multiple documents (though if it does, I'd be happy to be corrected).  The print shop can probably do this easily because they have specialized (and expensive) imposition software (google Quite Imposing for example). You can copy PDF content into other programs; you might set up a template/grid in a graphics program and copy/paste from each PDF into it.

Comment: The pro version allows you to quite easily combine separate files (of any document or image kind) into a single PDF, which you can then print. As 60x4 and 60x3 leave whitespace on an A4 (210x297mm), I also assume the sticky sheet is not precut, so the exact placement or order do not matter.

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: It seems to me that you could simply use insert your PDF's into a single page A4 document in either Microsoft Word or LibreOffice Draw (or many other applications).  If you need help on this, ask about how to do it in a particular application (along with what you've tried and why it hasn't worked).